# Phyton3: Updating a list after removing an item and

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing the following exercise:

> **Program: Foot Bones Quiz**
>
> Create a function that will iterate through foot_bones looking for a
>   match of a string argument
>
> Call the function 2 times with the name of a footbone and provide feedback for each answer (correct - incorrect)
>
> print the total # of foot_bones identified The program will use the foot_bones list:

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]
```

> Bonus: remove correct response item from list if correct so user cannot answer same item twice

This is the code I have written for "calcaneus":

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]
def quiz_bones(bone_insert,foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]):
    for bone in foot_bones:
        if bone==bone_insert:
            print("There is",foot_bones.count(bone_insert),bone_insert,"in",foot_bones)
            foot_bones=foot_bones.remove(bone_insert)
            return True
        else:
            print("There is ",foot_bones.count(bone_insert),bone_insert,"in",foot_bones)
            return False

print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=input("Type a bone: ")),"that calcaneus","is in",foot_bones)
print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=input("Type a bone: ")),"that calcaneus","is in",foot_bones)
```

Which gives me the following:

```
Type a bone: calcaneus
There is 1 calcaneus in ['calcaneus', 'talus', 'cuboid', 'navicular', 'lateral cuneiform', 'intermediate cuneiform', 'medial cuneiform']
It is:  True that calcaneus is in ['calcaneus', 'talus', 'cuboid', 'navicular', 'lateral cuneiform', 'intermediate cuneiform', 'medial cuneiform']
Type a bone: calcaneus
There is  0 calcaneus in ['talus', 'cuboid', 'navicular', 'lateral cuneiform', 'intermediate cuneiform', 'medial cuneiform']
It is:  False that calcaneus is in ['calcaneus', 'talus', 'cuboid', 'navicular', 'lateral cuneiform', 'intermediate cuneiform', 'medial cuneiform'] #The list hasn't been updated because it is not part of the function.
```

How can I modify my code so the last statement shows the updated list after "calcaneus" has been removed?

Also, in this type of statement: *"It is:  True that calcaneus is in ['calcaneus', 'talus', 'cuboid', 'navicular', 'lateral cuneiform', 'intermediate cuneiform', 'medial cuneiform']"* I want to modify "calcaneus" for whatever the input is. However when I modify the last two lines of the code for:

```
print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=input("Type a bone: ")),"that",bone_insert,"is in",foot_bones)
print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=input("Type a bone: ")),"that",bone_insert,"is in",foot_bones)
```

I get the following:

```
Type a bone: calcaneus
There is 1 calcaneus in ['calcaneus', 'talus', 'cuboid', 'navicular', 'lateral cuneiform', 'intermediate cuneiform', 'medial cuneiform']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8992c9c37974> in <module>()
     14             return False
     15 
---> 16 print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=input("Type a bone: ")),"that",bone_insert,"is in",foot_bones)
     17 print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=input("Type a bone: ")),"that",bone_insert,"is in",foot_bones)

NameError: name 'bone_insert' is not defined
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: have you considered making a function to print and pass the list as an argument to the print function wherever you want to print

Comment: You are printing the original list that you are passing as argument to the function. Your list is only modified within the scope of the function. You should return the modified list and then print it. Careful with variable scoping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=input("Type a bone: ")),"that",bone_insert,"is in",foot_bones)
```

In this code first `bone_insert` is a name of the parameter passes to the function, not a variable.

To make this work, just do this in multiple lines:

```
bone_insert = input("Type a bone: ")
print("It is: ",quiz_bones(bone_insert=bone_insert),"that",bone_insert,"is in",foot_bones)
```

---

> How can I modify my code so the last statement shows the updated list after "calcaneus" has been removed?

The problem is you use a different list inside and outside the function.

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]
def quiz_bones(bone_insert,foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]):
```

Those two have the same names, but one is a global variable, the other is local.

Just remove the second parameter:

```
def quiz_bones(bone_insert):
```

Now the function will see that there is no `foot_bones` in local scope, so it will look up!

But:

```
foot_bones=foot_bones.remove(bone_insert)
```

This line is wrong. `list.remove` does not return anything (you would overwrite your list with `None`!) and you cannot change global variables without saying you want to.

Just do:

```
foot_bones.remove(bone_insert)
```

Now you only operate on the insides of the list (which works because list is mutable).

Comment: That's correct. Although I wouldn't suggest to mutate a global variable, but rather get the function to return the local variable. Not a big fan of side effects :-)

Comment: If it was my code, I'd probably pass it always when using. But it looks like OP is a beginner and it's a simple script. Just doing the fix that was asked for, with explanation, instead of doing the whole script for them. ;)

Comment: @h4z3 fair enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

i think doing somthing with filter will be helpful for you. caues you want to remove the item after the search.
there are many options.
note this is just an example i whould try to make it look nicer then what i did probably remove some vars.
but this is a personal tast.

somthing like that

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]

selected_item = 'calcaneus' #for example

def look_for_match(item):
    return selected_item not in item

list_without_selectd_item = list(filter(look_for_match, foot_bones))
number_of_apperences = len(foot_bones) - len(list_without_selectd_item)
print(f'the {selected_item} apper {number_of_apperences} times')
selected_item = 'talus'
list_after_two_filters = list(filter(look_for_match, list_without_selectd_item))
number_of_apperences_second_filter = len(list_without_selectd_item) - len(list_after_two_filters)
print(f'the {selected_item} apper {number_of_apperences_second_filter} times')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the input to a variable and remove after the result.

```
f_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]

def quiz_bones(bone_insert, foot_bones):
    for bone in foot_bones:
        if bone == bone_insert:
            print("There is",foot_bones.count(bone_insert),bone_insert,"in",foot_bones)            
            print('foot_bones')
            return True, foot_bones
        else:
            print("There is ",foot_bones.count(bone_insert),bone_insert,"in",foot_bones)
            return False, foot_bones

while True:
    bone_insert = input("Type a bone: ") # assign input to a varialbe
    res, f_bones = quiz_bones(bone_insert, foot_bones=f_bones)    # return  modified list
    print("It is: ",res,"that", bone_insert, "is in",f_bones) # print Result
    if res: # if result is True.
        f_bones.remove(bone_insert) # remove item from list.
```